How to acquire exclusive lock in replicated mysql and clustered servers?
I have this scenario:
My php web application is deployed in a clustered environment, it uses a replicated mariadb database with galera.
It has to acquire an exclusive lock on database row resource and proceed with a process that has to be done abolutely once and from just one server.
I must be sure that in case of concurrent multiple requests coming to the same, or different, servers just one request will pass.
When the application was warking in a single server environmente this was the logic:

There was a column in resource table with the process status, let say processed with default 0. 0=not processed, 1=already processed.
The isolation transaction level was set to READ COMMITTED.
When the controller acquired the request, it entered in transaction with this query: SELECT processed FROM mytable WHERE id=? FOR UPDATE.
If the query returned processed=0, It safetly proceded with the process, updated the processes status to 1 and commited the transaction. Otherwise, if processed value is >0 it would have skipped the process.

I have tested many times this implementation and it worked. The concurrent requests will be stopped waiting for the READ LOCK on the id index and just the first one proceeded to the next step. The isolation level to READ COMMITTED will ensure to get the last updated value of the semaphore column.
The problems started with the replicated database environment.
It looks like the READ LOCK in replicated MariaDB is optimistic, it starts the transation without waiting the lock acquisition and it will check for collision only at commit time.
So if I have 2 concurrent transactions, both are not stopped at  FOR UPDATE query and both will get 0 value for the processed semaphore field. At commit one will win and other will fail. But it is too late. Of course this is not acceptable in my case because I have already let run my unique process two times.
How can I safely change my logic to suit the replicated environment?
How can be implemented a patter of exclusive resource lock with a replicated db?

Since Galera is not designed for write scalability nor synchronous replication, the ideal pattern for conflict-free usage of Galera is to always write to a single node but read from any node. The exact problem you are facing is why people tend to avoid writing to multiple Galera nodes at the same time: deadlocks on COMMIT seem to be rarely handled by the application in a graceful manner.
A convenient solution to this problem that requires no changes in your application is to hide the complexity of the Galera cluster behind a smart SQL load balancer like MariaDB MaxScale. This will make your locking pattern work out-of-the-box with a Galera cluster. However, this does come at the cost of having to run the proxy on a separate node.
In MaxScale, the Galera monitor module takes care of figuring out which node to write to in a consistent manner across multiple MaxScale instances. The readwritesplit router is what takes care of load balancing the reads and writes correctly. Combined together, they make MaxScale appear as if it was a single database but with the robustness of a whole Galera cluster.
Here's an example configuration that takes care of sending writes to only one Galera node while still distributing reads to all nodes, all in a transactionally safe manner.
[maxscale]
threads=auto

[node-1]
type=server
address=192.168.0.2

[node-2]
type=server
address=192.168.0.3

[node-3]
type=server
address=192.168.0.4

[Galera-Cluster]
type=monitor
servers=node-1,node-2,node-3
user=monitor_user
password=monitor_pw

[RW-Router]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
cluster=Galera-Cluster
user=service_user
password=service_pw

[RW-Port]
type=listener
service=RW-Router
port=3306

The MaxScale tutorial has more information about how to get started.

Thanks Markusjm, it is definitly something to check. I have few doubt if it is usable in my environment because currently I have only 2 server. Moreover I did not understand if the r/w router split logic is bypassed if the write node is not reachable.

It should work just fine with two nodes, you'll just have very limited HA due to no tolerance for lost nodes. MaxScale will send writes to the node with the lowest wsrep_local_index value but if configured with root_node_as_master, it'll only use the node with an index value of 0. This makes it possible for any number of MaxScales to send writes to the same node in the same cluster.

The logic with which the routing is done in readwritesplit is documented here. There's three classes of operations: read, writes and session state modifications. The reads and writes are somewhat obvious and the session state modifications are things like SET NAMES latin1, SET SQL_MODE=... and USE my_db that modify how things work in MariaDB. For your use-case, the important thing is that  SELECT ... FOR UPDATE will always be sent to the correct node.

Galera transactions are optimistic locking so any transactional integrity between nodes is enforced on COMMIT. Those failing the optimistic locking will receive a deadlock error.
As a solution:
Ensure the application patterns, like you have, than need pessimistic locking access the same Galera node.
Also applicable to your application SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED so more than one application worker process can aquire and process form the worker list.
A non-Galera solution is to place the not-processed primary keys (id) of the table onto a durable message queue (e.g. RabbitMQ) where multiple applications can consume this and update the database when complete.

Thank you for your tips. I'll take a look for some pessimist lock patterns. I already considered RabbitMQ workers but I don't think it fits very well the apache/php technology I'm using.

There's AMQP php pecl's that work with a variety of MQs. Not integrated like pdo/mysqli however seemly actively maintained elsewhere. Single node databases already a pessimistic lock pattern.

My doubt was not related to the library integration but how to maintain active all workers and handle threads. I opened another question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78635662/how-to-start-php-workers-in-a-safe-way?noredirect=1#comment138638280_78635662 Moreover I'm checking if it is possibile to use pessimistic lock with Galera and it seems not possibile. Probably I need to refactor a big part of my sw.
